# Can I just include a script in ebextensions instead of having to build one?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have seen examples like this for creating and running a script via ebextensions config:

```
files:
  "C:\\scripts\\whoami.ps1":
    content: |
      date       | out-file -append c:\scripts\whoami.log
      whoami     | out-file -append c:\scripts\whoami.log
      hostname   | out-file -append c:\scripts\whoami.log
      get-module | out-file -append c:\scripts\whoami.log

commands:
  whoami:
    command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\\scripts\\whoami.ps1"
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 5
```

That's fine, but can I just include a script in ebextensions and refer to it instead of having to define its content in a config?

for example I would have

```
myapp
--.ebextensions
----myconfig.config
----myscript.ps1
```

And then "myconfig.config" would copy "myscript.ps1" somewhere and run it.

How can I do this?

Edit:
So I put this command in a config to see what the current path is:

```
commands:
  whereami:
    command: dir > c:\whereami.log
    ignoreErrors: false
    waitAfterCompletion: 5
```

Its `c:\windows\system32` which makes sense because it runs in the context of SYSTEM.

Is there no self referential method/keyword I can use to point to a script I have located in the beanstalk project I upload?

Comment: When do you want to run this script in relation to when your app is deployed? Is it dependent on your app already being deployed?  Is your app deployment dependent on this script already being run? Will you need access to environment variables in the script?

Comment: Just want to know how I can put a script somewhere in my project (maybe even inside the .ebextensions folder?) and call it via an ebextensions config

Comment: Have you tried to just store the file in your main source code and then use a container command?

Comment: Hmm well I'm not running containers- EC2 with EBS. Will the container command still work? I just assumed that it was only for actual ECS containers

Comment: Yes, the container command gets run right before your app is deployed.  So you could do something like: container_command: run_my_script: command: "bin/my_script.sh" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands (where the bin directory is in the root of your app)

Comment: OK that works! But is there a way to put my scripts in .ebextensions or some folder external to the project? If possible I'd like to not have them deployed to the application folder. Could I somehow have them in the temporary "c:\staging" folder that gets created and then deleted during a deploy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130819/discussion-between-littleforest-and-red888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options that worked for me (thanks to littleforest).

Create a folder structure inside of the web deployment package and refer to it with **container_commands**:

```
package/myfolder/myscript.ps1

container_commands:
  relativeprogrampath:
    command: "myfolder/myscript.ps1"
```

Create it in a parent folder and refer to it:

example folder structure:

```
parentfolder/myfolder/myscript.ps1
parentfolder/package/<the web deployment package>

container_commands:
  relativeprogrampath:
    command: "..\myscript.ps1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you place the `myscript.ps1` file in the `.ebextensions` folder next to the config files, you can run it from a container command like this:

```
container_commands:
  00-myscript:
    command: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ".\\.ebextensions\\myscript.ps1"
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
```